# Term for addictive song, replayed too many times it is hated or neutral now

Tags: single-word-requests, music, songs

I looked thoroughly on the internet, but I failed to find a term or single word (if exists any) for a song that is so addictive that you replay it again and again although you know you will hate it soon, or at most it'll become neutral to you. I found *earworm*, but it is about an unwanted song that is stuck in your head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The song itself *can* be said to be an [**earworm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earworm):

> An earworm, sometimes known as a brainworm, sticky music, or stuck song syndrome, is a catchy piece of music that continually repeats through a person's mind after it is no longer playing.

This is not necessarily a derogatory term, although the experience is often negative.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to emphasize how the song was once enjoyable but has become odious, you could call it a carnivorous/poisonous/rotten earworm.

Comment: Generally an "earworm" is considered to be a song that "gets into your head" and which you find yourself humming (or at least "replaying" in your mind) when there is no external audio to drown it out.  This is different from a song you obsessively replay on a music player.

Comment: Well, I'm still not convinced with this answer. If i said "Yesterday I played the earmworm all day and now I hate it", would that be understandable?

Comment: It isn't clear from the question who was playing the song. I assumed it was being played on broadcast media. If you yourself were playing it, then I agree, earworm doesn't work as well.

Comment: @HotLicks You mean like "a catchy piece of music that continually repeats through a person's mind after it is no longer playing"? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Not a single word, but a song like that is described as being "played to death". This [Huffington Post entry](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/first-dance-songs-that-havent-been-played-to-death_us_570d7ecde4b08a2d32b84b23) shows the usage, as I'm struggling to find a dictionary entry at the moment.

Comment: I feel like this best matches the sentiment of the question - Ex: Taylor swift was catchy until the local radio played her to death.

Answer (score 2):

*[Catchy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/catchy) songs* are frequently *overplayed*

> 1. Attractive or appealing: a catchy idea for a new television series.
> 2. Easily remembered: a song with a catchy tune. [MWD]

Comment: I guess that would be a catchy numb-er